# Accessing FTPS using RCurl

Tags: r, rcurl, ftps

I have an FTPS server which I can already work with using clients such as Filezilla and Syncback. I also have admin access to this FTPS server and I know that it is working properly with TLS because I see "TLS" in the Filezilla connection log.

I cannot, however, access this same FTPS server from R using the RCurl library (R version=3.4.3, RCurl version = 1.95-4.9, windows 7 PC). I expect it has something to do with my invocation of getURL(). Here's what happens when I try to list the files in a directory on the FTPS server:

```
library(RCurl)
url       <- "FTPS://<myIpaddress>/<path>/"
userpwd   <- "myname:mypasswd"
filenames <- getURL(url, userpwd=userpwd, ftp.use.epsv = FALSE, dirlistonly = TRUE, .opts=curlOptions(verbose=TRUE))
```

[image: first attempt: connection refused on port 990]

It complains about connection refused on port 990 (presumably the default port for FTPS?). I happen to have the FTPS server setup to use port 21. Filezilla didn't require a port number so I had left it out here too. Explicitly specifying port 21, however, gives another problem...

```
url <- "FTPS://<myIpaddress>:21/<path>/"
```

[image: second attempt: unknown protocol]

This time the complaint is about "unknown protocol". Don't understand. I am using a FTPS server listening on port 21, I specify the same on the URL. What could be wrong?

Can anyone recommend some ways to troubleshoot this further?

For completeness here's the FTPS server configuration (it's a synology diskstation NAS)...
[image]

Comment: Hello, did you ever manage to solve this?

Comment: Any idea how to solve this? I have the same problem...

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I worked around it by accessing the NAS as a fileshare (with a UNC filepath) instead of accessing it via FTPS.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get Data from Secure FTP with RCurl::getURL()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63746562/get-data-from-secure-ftp-with-rcurlgeturl)

Comment: @patrickmdnet, it seems plausible, I wish I had tried that in 2017 !

Answer (score 0):

Add `ftp.ssl = TRUE` to the `getURL` options for SFTP.

This is the equivalent of `--ftp-ssl` in actual curl.